# i want to create this iphone tableview feature same in android view?

Tags: android, listview

hii i want to create this same iphone tableview feature in android how to do this
is there any idea how to do this in android listview is available i think it is nearest to listview how to without change listview item display delete button i put image here so you can check it

> When i click on edit button display delete button in every row of
>   listview

[image]

> After click button listview change like this image

[image]

Comment: why this is tagged in iOS?

Comment: just change visibility of "red minus" when you click on edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getView()` source code for handling visibility of delete button on the click of edit.

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;
            TextView playerNameTextView, gameStatusTextView ;

            final NotiMyTurn notiItem = this.noti.get(position);

            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }

            playerNameTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_my_turn_player_name);
            gameStatusTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_my_turn_game_status);
            img_game_play = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_my_turn_play);
            img_player_delete = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_player_delete_button);
            img_player_pic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_player_pic_my_turn);

            playerNameTextView.setText(notiItem.playerName);
            gameStatusTextView.setText(notiItem.gameStatus);

            if(editMode)
            {
                    //img_game_play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    img_player_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img_player_delete.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_in));
                    img_player_pic.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move));
                    playerNameTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move));
                    gameStatusTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move));
                    img_game_play.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_out));

            }
            else
            {
                if(isEditClickedFirst)
                {
                    img_game_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img_player_delete.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_out));
                    img_player_pic.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move_back));
                    playerNameTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move_back));
                    gameStatusTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move_back));
                    img_game_play.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_in));

                }
                img_player_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return row;
        }
```